# iOS Hiding tab bar in iOS 6 creates black bar (fix for iOS 6 breaks iOS 7!)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I've got a tabbed application and in one tab there is a `UIWebView`. When I rotate the device to landscape I've made the `UIWebView` full screen while hiding the status and tab bar.

I've got it working in iOS 6 - originally when rotating and hiding the tab bar it would leave a black space where the tab bar was, so the `fHeight` code fixes this. However, on iOS 6 it worked perfectly, but now it actually creates the black bar problem iOS 6 was having!! Any ideas for a workaround to this?

Please see my edit below this

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    }

    for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height - 49.0;

    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width - 49.0;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

//Edit

I've tried using this but I'm not sure how to pass in the view properly - I've tried `self.view` and webView and others but I can't get it to work on both iOS 6 and 7! Any kind of idea at all would be really helpful! Let me know if you need more info

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden view:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.tabBar.hidden == hidden)
        return;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float height = 0.0f;

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        height = screenRect.size.width;
    }
    else
    {
        height = screenRect.size.height;
    }

    if (!hidden)
    {
        height -= CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame);
    }

    void (^workerBlock)() = ^() {

        self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.tabBar.frame), height, CGRectGetWidth(self.tabBar.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBar.frame));
        view.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(view.frame), CGRectGetMinY(view.frame), CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), height);
    };

    void (^completionBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished) {
        self.tabBar.hidden = hidden;
    };

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:workerBlock completion:completionBlock];
    }
    else
    {
        workerBlock();
        completionBlock(YES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got this working, but it took a while. It stemmed from a mixture of my original code and some of JRG-Developers work.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    BOOL toLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    void (^workerBlock)() = ^() {


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:toLandscape withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

        float height = toLandscape ? screenRect.size.width : screenRect.size.height - CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame);

        float width = toLandscape ? screenRect.size.height : screenRect.size.width;

        webView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(webView.frame),
                               CGRectGetMinY(webView.frame),
                               width,
                               height);

        [self moveTabBarToPosition:height];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:workerBlock];
}
//Moving the tab bar and its subviews offscreen so that top is at position y
-(void)moveTabBarToPosition:(int)y {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, y, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

    for(UIView *view in self.tabBarController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, y)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
}
```

In my case this is for my webview but theoretically you can give it any view. Works in iOS 6 and 7

Answer (score 6):

I've created a a public [Gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/JRG-Developer/6714930) for how we're doing this.

This solution has gone through several iterations due to [@Chris Byatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066487/chris-byatt) and our team trying it out. So, make sure you download the latest revision from there.

The method signature has been simplified to

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

You can call it like this within your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
[self.tabBarController setTabBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: I can't figure out which view to put in to get it working on iOS 6 and 7 - is it `self.view` or the UIWebView or what?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to call this? I can't seem to get it to work at all..

Comment: This is how I'm calling it to hide it `[self setTabBarHidden:YES view:self.view animated:YES];` (I have animated:YES as method defines it as a bool?) and to bring it back `[self setTabBarHidden:NO view:self.view animated:YES];` but I'm getting the black bar still, and when I try and bring it back the tab bar doesn't come back at all!

Comment: And this is the mask I have on my UIWebView `wv.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);`

Comment: I see what you mean, there was an issue with iOS 6 and this code. I've updated the code to fix this. :D

Comment: It should work well now for both iOS 6 and iOS 7. Otherwise, let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: I've got it working in iOS 7 but it still leaves a black bar at the bottom in iOS 6

Comment: Are you testing on the device or simulator? Did you copy the new code given? (Not the "How to Use" section)

Comment: Simulator. Sorry - I did not see you'd updated that code. I'll give it a go now

Comment: Err... found issue. Re-posted. Please copy again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38108/discussion-between-chris-byatt-and-jrg-developer)

Comment: sent some screenshots in chat

Comment: There are 5 revisions (versions) of this Gist.. it looks like you somehow downloaded an older version. Delete the files and make sure you download the latest version (currently revision 5).

Comment: I downloaded the latest revision and it just does not work. I will post my solution.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution that works for you. Great. :D We've revised the Gist based on your commentary... it now switches based on `iOS 6` or `iOS 7` and using specific animation blocks for each. Seems to work for our purposes at least. :D

Comment: thanks for posting your gist, huge help.  by the way, in IOS 7 I had to click the settings for "Under Bottom Bars" and "Under Opaque Bars" in the storyboard for this to work correctly.  I believe they can also be set in code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

OK guys, after struggling with this for about two hours, my colleague taught me the right way to do it. There is actually a very simple fix that I can't find online:

just put :

```
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

In the init method of your viewController and comment out the self.tabBar.hidden related code.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) hideBottomTabs{
// Get the size of the main screen
CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0){
    UITabBar *bar = ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBarController.tabBar;
    fullScreenRect.size.height += ViewHeight(bar);
}
// Hide the tab bar
((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
// Resize and fill the screen
[[((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:fullScreenRect];
```

}

I have solved my problem in a such way.

Comment: i use the same idea too