# Tap to toggle fullscreen - issues with opaque tabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm trying to make my app "fullscreen" on user tap in a single view by hiding both statusBar, navigationBar and tabBar together.

I can hide and show the navigationBar and the status bar fine, but I'm facing some issues while hiding the tabBar.

This is what it looks like before hiding it:
[image]
And this after hiding it:
[image]
When hiding, the tabBar leaves a blank spot, which I've tried to hide without success.

This is the code I'm currently using

```
-(void)toggleBars:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    //Hide navigationBar    
    BOOL toggleNavigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!toggleNavigationBar animated:YES];


    //Hide tabBar - not hiding, leaving a black spot
    BOOL toggleTabHidden = self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden;
    [self.tabBarController setTabBarHidden:!toggleTabHidden];

    //Hide statusBar
    BOOL statusBarHidden = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!statusBarHidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate){
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

I've googled a lot and even looked up here on SO but I didn't find anything that could help me.

**Visually this is what I'm trying to achieve**

```
----------------                  --------------
|navBar &statbar|                |              |  
|---------------                 |              |
|               |      tap       |              | 
|   content     |     ----->     | content only |         
|               |                |in fullscreen |
|               |                |              |
|-------------- |                |              |
|    tabbar     |                |              |
 -------------                    --------------
```

**TL;DR**

I would like to make my app fullscreen on tap and I would like to know how to remove the blank spot that the tabBar leaves when hiding it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

I've followed the answer by [Sebastian Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289841/sebastian-keller) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225450/hiding-tabbar-showing-black-bar-in-ios7/19658778#19658778), the blank tabBar is now hidden but the animation is a little big buggy and not smooth.

**EDIT 2**

After creating a dummy project, I've remade my Storyboard and I noticed that the problem is that, when the tabBar is set to opaque, it leaves the blank bar behind. This doesn't apply when it's set to translucent.

Here's a [dummy project to demonstrate the issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20375801/HideTest.zip).

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? I think I might have a solution for you.

Comment: Yes I'm using Autolayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the method suggested in [the answer I've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22834617/781322). With some tweaking it was working.

Comment: I think it was that call to `layoutSubviews` that is the key

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it when run into that black bar. The animation is smooth as it should.
This code uses the great **FrameAccessor** class that you can find here: https://github.com/AlexDenisov/FrameAccessor

So instead of this:

```
CGRect newFrame = view.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 15;
view.frame = newFrame;
```

We can do this:

```
view.x = 15;
```

---

This would be a lot easier. Subclass UITabBar controller and select it in your UITabBar Controller custom class.

[image]

**SSTabBarController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SSTabBarController : UITabBarController
@property (assign) BOOL isTabBarOpen;

-(void)showOrHideTabBar;
- (void)hideTabBarWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)showTabBarWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

**SSTabBarController.m:**

```
#import "SSTabBarController.h"
#import "FrameAccessor.h"

#define IPHONE_HEIGHT [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
#define TABBAR_HEIGHT 49

@interface SSTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation SSTabBarController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     //This part is optional. If you are using opaque tabbar you can mark extend edged in your `StoryBoard`.
        /*UIView *tabBarBackround = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen          mainScreen].bounds.size.height-TABBAR_HEIGHT, 320, TABBAR_HEIGHT)];
    tabBarBackround.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:236/255.0 green:236/255.0 blue:236/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarBackround];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.tabBar aboveSubview:tabBarBackround];*/

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)showOrHideTabBar
{
    if(_isTabBarOpen)
    {
        [self hideTabBarWithAnimation:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showTabBarWithAnimation:YES];
    }
}

- (void)showTabBarWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated
{
    _isTabBarOpen = YES;
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
             if(animated)
             {
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^()
                  {
                      view.y = IPHONE_HEIGHT - view.height;
                  }
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
             }
            else
            {
                view.y = IPHONE_HEIGHT - view.height;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)hideTabBarWithAnimation:(BOOL)animated
{
    _isTabBarOpen = NO;
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
             if(animated)
             {
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^()
                  {
                      view.y = IPHONE_HEIGHT;
                  }
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
             }
            else
            {
                view.y = IPHONE_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
    }
}
@end
```

In any other `ViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)hideTabbar:(UIButton *)sender
{

    SSTabBarController *myTabBar = (SSTabBarController*)self.tabBarController;
    [myTabBar showOrHideTabBar];
}
```

If you use opaque make sure this is checked in you `UITabBarController` and your `ViewController`:

[image]

**Here's a working project with the above you can download:** http://bit.ly/10fSxkU

Comment: What's the IPHONE_HEIGHT constant?

Comment: Well, the iPhone height :). Edited my answer

Comment: Yeah guessed so haha anyway view.y generates an error. shouldn't it be something like view.frame.origin.y?

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I'm using a great GREAT class called FrameAccessor that solves just that, Highly recommended. https://github.com/AlexDenisov/

Comment: Tried with no luck unfortunately. The bar doesn't even move

Comment: Do you have an example project you can upload?

Comment: This is weird. While testing the dummy project the animation works. I think that's something in my storyboard at this point.

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Subclassing would be a bullet proof solution.

Comment: I'll give a shot to the edited storyboard, if doesn't work i'll try subclassing. +1 for you meanwhile!

Comment: Got the problem. The bar appears when the tabBar style is set to opaque rather than translucent.

Comment: Tried your code. The bar is still there because of the opaque problem I guess.

Comment: No problem, you can change the color of the background to what ever you like. Check out the `viewDidLoad` of `SSTabBarController` in the edited answer above.

Comment: Another edit. Instead of adding a view with a background color to your UITabBar you can just extend the edges as described in the picture that was added to the answer. The area will still get touches after the TabBar is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to hide the tab bar not by stretching down the `UITabBarController.view` just enough to bring its `tabBar` offscreen:

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    CGRect frame = self.originalViewFrame;
    if (hidden)
    {
        frame.size.height += self.tabBar.size.height;
    }
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

This automatically stretches contained controllers' views nicely.

Code [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUKit/blob/master/Source/Additions/UITabBarController+NBUAdditions.m#L34).

Answer (score -1):

Using the following code, which is almost identical to your own, I'm having no trouble reproducing your desired effect:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleBars)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
}

- (void)toggleBars {
    BOOL toggleNavigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!toggleNavigationBar animated:YES];

    BOOL toggleTabHidden = self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:!toggleTabHidden];

    BOOL statusBarHidden = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!statusBarHidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

Video demonstration:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vzgfxc5f043lxy/hide.mov?dl=0

Comment: I've tried, but unfortunately the blank bar keeps popping :(