# Hide TabBar in iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uitabbar

I want to Hide my TabBar in `iOS 6`, when i wrote the code which is given below it works in `iOS 7` but it shows black line in `iOS 6`

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Here is snapshot for  `iOS 6`

[image]:

Comment: Can you double check that `self.tabBarController` isn't `null` in iOS 6?

Comment: The Same Question with Solution Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006545/ios-hiding-tab-bar-in-ios-6-creates-black-bar-fix-for-ios-6-breaks-ios-7

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: when i log `self.tabBarController` it shows `<UITabBarController: 0xc087150>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006545/ios-hiding-tab-bar-in-ios-6-creates-black-bar-fix-for-ios-6-breaks-ios-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code May be this will help you...

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{        
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
            {
                 [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 568 +20, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                 [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480+20, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 568)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 519, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==568)
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 519)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this ?(isiPhone5?568:480)+20

Comment: I have implemented BOOL in appdel for this if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {
        isiPhone5=YES;
    }

Comment: @Krunal sry for that now check answer

Comment: Dude but how to call this methods ?

Comment: @Krunal are you created your UITabBar in AppDelegate view?

Comment: yes, `UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42465/discussion-between-pradhyuman-chavda-and-krunal)

Comment: That code will break as soon as the iPhone6 or 7 comes with different screen sizes. You are far better off with using things like window.bounds.size as variables and calculate with them. Avoid constants like 568 and 480. These constants are doomed to fail earlier or later.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing view controller just use

```
yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[yourTabbarNavigationController pushViewController:helpViewController animated:YES];
```

This will remove black transculent layer,but if u are using custom tabbar then you will have to explicitly hide those view also.