# Need TabBar to be shown again when I pop the ViewController in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, mobile-application

In iOS 7, TabBar hides when I used `nextviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`
 but need tabbar to be shown again when I pop back to the viewcontroller.
Its not coming back by using `nextviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;`
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this solved my problem:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES; 
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this also but it is not working properly. Please suggest any other solution. I did search a lot for this problem  :(

Comment: Hey,Thanks user3118121 .. This solved my issue. Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 6):

I found simplest way to achieve hide and show of UITabBar.

```
nextviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextviewcontroller animated:YES];
nextviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

So right after you push the view controller set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO; this way Tabbar would be shown when you come back to view controller.

Comment: Yes, I did this but its not working. Definitely it will hide tabbar in nextviewcontroller but I am not getting tabbar back in previous view. any other solution?

Comment: @Pinky check my this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368589/hide-tabbar-in-ios-6/20368641#20368641

Comment: if any queries then ask me

Comment: For me the first two lines (without the third) worked perfectly.